# Missing all data due to one join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an order class

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string customerId { get; set; }
    public string sellerId { get; set; }
    public float lat{ get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
    public int orderAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime orderDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime deliveredTime { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string orderStatus { get; set; }
    public int reviewId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("reviewId")]
    public virtual Reviews Reviews { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicatoinUser Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicatoinUser Seller { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order_Items> Order_Items { get; set; }
```

then I have a Reviews class

```
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string customerID { get; set; }

    public string sellerID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public string description { set; get; }

    [ForeignKey("customerID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("sellerID")]
    public virtual ApplicatoinUser Seller { get; set; }
```

Then I tried this query

```
var order = (from x in _context.Orders where x.Id == orderId select new
            {
                x.Seller,
                Order_Items = from a in x.Order_Items select new
                {
                 a.id, a.Quantity, a.mandatory,
                 Price = new
                 {
                     a.Price.FruitsAndVegs,a.Price.Date,a.Price.id, a.Price.priceA, a.Price.priceB
                 }
                },
                Reviews = new
                {
                    x.Reviews.id,
                    x.Reviews.Rating,
                    x.Reviews.description,
                },
                x.orderAmount,x.orderDateTime, x.orderStatus, x.lat, x.lng,x.reviewId, x.deliveredTime,
                x.description
            });
```

When I call it from postman or my main app I get this result:

[image: Results]

but when I tried

```
var order = (from x in _context.Orders where x.Id == orderId select new
            {
                x.Seller,
                Order_Items = from a in x.Order_Items select new
                {
                 a.id, a.Quantity, a.mandatory,
                 Price = new
                 {
                     a.Price.FruitsAndVegs,a.Price.Date,a.Price.id, a.Price.priceA, a.Price.priceB
                 }
                },
                x.orderAmount,x.orderDateTime, x.orderStatus, x.lat, x.lng,x.reviewId, x.deliveredTime,
                x.description
            });
```

then I get this result:

[image]

What can be the reason that review object is calling?

Note: my review foreign key is null.

But Customer and Seller is also null but they are showing it as null.

Review is causing problems from me

Comment: DO NOT use the `visual-studio` tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can someone please answer